# How do I obtain all the files within list through iteration?

Tags: python, os.path

I created a list with specific extensions I would like to obtain through the directories C:\ and D:\. But I am having a problem obtaining multiple files. If I were to just put 'python.exe' in the list and removing 'Hearthstone.exe' it can find and print and append it to the VIP_files list. But as soon as I add 'Hearthstone.exe' nothing happens, not even the 'python.exe' path is given. This is what I have, I am not to sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import os
from os.path import join

lookfor = ['python.exe','Hearthstone.exe']
VIP_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\', 'D:\\'):
    if lookfor in files:
        print ("found: %s" % join(root, lookfor))
        VIP_files.append(root+ lookfor)

print(VIP_files)
```

Comment: yes because the files will be in alphabetical order, `lookfor` should be in alphabetical order `lookfor = ['Hearthstone.exe', 'python.exe']`

Comment: the typo I editted was not the problem right? You did have a closing quote on `'heartstone.exe`? And you have to do `if any(x in lookfor for x in files)`.

Comment: alphabetical order is the issue.

Comment: `lookfor` is a list, however you are using it like a single string. I think this is the problem.

Comment: @stack I tried that it didn't work.

Comment: @gzc how would I go about this problem?

Comment: @ev.kounis It was a typo on my part, I will try what you suggested.

Comment: @DJRodrigue check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lookfor` is a list and so is `files`. What you're asking python to do in your `if` is check if a list is in a list, like, `[['python.exe','Hearthstone.exe'], ...]`, which of course doesn't exist.

A quick fix is to make `lookfor` a set and then use set intersections like this:

```
import os
from os.path import join

lookfor = {'python.exe','Hearthstone.exe'}  # {} set syntax
VIP_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\', 'D:\\'):
    found = lookfor.intersection(files)
    for f in found:
        print("found: {}".format(root + f))
        VIP_files.append(root + f)

print(VIP_files)
```